# Close a Java NIO Socket Channel without closing the underlying TCP Socket

Tags: scala, sockets, nio

Closing a particular ChannelSocket actually closes the TCP socket also. Even when the `keep-alive` is set to true.

```scala
val socketChannel = selectionKey.channel().asInstanceOf[SocketChannel]

socketChannel.socket().setKeepAlive(true)

socketChannel.close()

println("Socket closed?", socketChannel.socket().isClosed) // prints true
```

I just want to close the socket channel so that I don't want to listen to more events on this channel. But I want to keep the connection open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem using `interestOps` method that is available on every`SelectionKey`.

In case you don't want to listen for any more events you can use `interestOps(0)`

```scala
val socketChannel = selectionKey.channel().asInstanceOf[SocketChannel]

socketChannel.socket().setKeepAlive(true)
// socketChannel.close()

selectionKey.interestOps(0) // Stops listening on events

println("Socket closed?", socketChannel.socket().isClosed) // prints false
```